# Weird behaviour when passing grandchild output of CreateProcess to the grandparent through the child

Tags: c, winapi, process, pipe, createprocess

I am working on an application A which calls `CreateProcess` to run a child process B, which in turn calls `createProcess` to run a child process C. The output of C should be passed through by B and then read by A. When I run B myself (outside of A), it works fine and the output of C is shown on the console. But when I run A, it gets to see all of B's output *except what has been passed on from C*. Apparently, I'm hitting a special case for grandchildren or something like that.

To experiment, I created a simple example `test.c`, which takes a digit as its argument. It outputs the letter corresponding to the digit (`a` for 1, etc.). It then starts the same program recursively using `CreateProcess`, but decreases the argument. It passes all output from the child in the format `<N: OUTPUT>`, where `N` is the digit argument.

I expect to see the following results:

```
> .\test.exe 1
a
> .\test.exe 2
b<2: a>
> .\test.exe 3
c<3: b><3: <2: a>>
```

I realize that due to buffering the last output may also be something like `c<3: b<2: a>>` --- the important thing is that the output `a` is nested in a `<2:>` block and that the `<2:>` block is nested in a `<3:>` block: this shows that the output of the grandchild is first received by the child and then passed on to the parent.

My program behaves correctly for arguments `1` and `2`, but for `3` I consistently get this output:

```
c<3: a><3: b<2: >>
```

This does not make sense to me at all. It is as if the output from the grandchild is received directly by the topmost process, because we get `<3: a>`. And I don't know how to interpret `<3: b<2: >>` either.

How do I fix this example so that the output of the grandchild is first seen by the child and then passed on to the parent?

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

static counter; /* the digit argument */
static HANDLE stdout_read;

static void error (char *s)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"error: %s\n",s);
    exit (1);
}

/* Thread function to pass through output */
static DWORD WINAPI copy_out_func (LPVOID unused)
{
    CHAR buffer[512];

    for (;;) {
        DWORD n_bytes;

        if (!ReadFile (stdout_read,buffer,sizeof (buffer),&n_bytes,NULL) || n_bytes==0)
            break;
        printf ("<%d: ",counter);
        WriteFile (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),buffer,n_bytes,&n_bytes,NULL);
        printf (">");
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE stdout_write,copy_out_thread;
    char cmd[64]=".\\test.exe";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
    STARTUPINFO si;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 

    if (argc != 2)
        error ("Usage: .\\test.exe N");

    counter = argv[1][0]-'0';

    if (counter <= 0)
        return 0; /* end recursion */

    printf ("%c",'a'+counter-1);

    sa.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    if (!CreatePipe (&stdout_read,&stdout_write,&sa,0))
        error ("CreatePipe");
    if (!SetHandleInformation (stdout_read,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0))
        error ("SetHandleInformation");
 
    ZeroMemory (&pi,sizeof (PROCESS_INFORMATION));
 
    ZeroMemory (&si,sizeof (STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO); 
    si.hStdOutput = stdout_write;
    si.hStdError = stdout_write;
    si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    cmd[10]=' ';
    cmd[11]='0' + (counter-1);
    cmd[12]='\0';
     
    if (!CreateProcess (NULL,cmd,NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
        error ("CreateProcess");

    CloseHandle (stdout_write);
    copy_out_thread = CreateThread (NULL,0,copy_out_func,NULL,0,NULL);

    CloseHandle (pi.hThread);

    WaitForSingleObject (pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject (copy_out_thread,INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I thought this could be because some handles of the grandparent were incorrectly inherited by the grandchild. So I created a somewhat longer example using `STARTUPINFOEX` with a `LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` to indicate that only two streams should be inherited. This program has the same faulty behaviour:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

static counter;
static HANDLE stdout_read;

static void error (char *s)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"error: %s (%d)\n",s,GetLastError());
    exit (1);
}

static DWORD WINAPI copy_out_func (LPVOID unused)
{
    CHAR buffer[512];

    for (;;) {
        DWORD n_bytes;

        if (!ReadFile (stdout_read,buffer,sizeof (buffer),&n_bytes,NULL) || n_bytes==0)
            break;
        printf ("<%d: ",counter);
        WriteFile (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),buffer,n_bytes,&n_bytes,NULL);
        printf (">");
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE stdout_write,copy_out_thread;
    char cmd[64]=".\\test.exe";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
    SIZE_T size;
    LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST lpAttributeList;
    HANDLE handlesToInherit[3];
    STARTUPINFOEX si;

    if (argc != 2)
        error ("Usage: .\\test.exe N");

    counter = argv[1][0]-'0';

    if (counter <= 0)
        return 0;

    printf ("%c",'a'+counter-1);

    sa.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    if (!CreatePipe (&stdout_read,&stdout_write,&sa,0))
        error ("CreatePipe");
    if (!SetHandleInformation (stdout_read,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0))
        error ("SetHandleInformation");
 
    ZeroMemory (&pi,sizeof (PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    handlesToInherit[0] = GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    handlesToInherit[1] = stdout_write;
    handlesToInherit[2] = NULL;
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList (NULL,1,0,&size);
    lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)(HeapAlloc (GetProcessHeap(),0,size));
    if (lpAttributeList == NULL)
        error ("HeapAlloc");
    if (!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList (lpAttributeList,1,0,&size))
        error ("InitializeProcThreadAttributeList");
    if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute (lpAttributeList,0,PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST,handlesToInherit,2*sizeof (HANDLE),NULL,NULL))
        error ("UpdateProcThreadAttribute");
 
    ZeroMemory (&si,sizeof (STARTUPINFOEX));
    si.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFOEX);
    si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = stdout_write;
    si.StartupInfo.hStdError = stdout_write;
    si.StartupInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    si.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.lpAttributeList = lpAttributeList;

    cmd[10]=' ';
    cmd[11]='0' + (counter-1);
    cmd[12]='\0';
     
    if (!CreateProcess (NULL,cmd,NULL,NULL,TRUE,EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,NULL,NULL,&si.StartupInfo,&pi))
        error ("CreateProcess");

    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList (lpAttributeList);
    HeapFree (GetProcessHeap(),0,lpAttributeList);

    CloseHandle (stdout_write);
    copy_out_thread = CreateThread (NULL,0,copy_out_func,NULL,0,NULL);

    CloseHandle (pi.hThread);

    WaitForSingleObject (pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject (copy_out_thread,INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was related to mixing `WriteFile` and `printf`. As I understand it, text printed with `printf` will be buffered and passed to `WriteFile` once the buffer is full (or, in this case, when the program exits). Because of this, if you `printf` A before you `WriteFile` B, A may actually appear *after* B.

The solution therefore is to use either `printf` (& friends) or `WriteFile` throughout, or to insert `fflush` before switching to the WinAPI.